# DB2 stored procedure - changing the table structure

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

I have to add a new column to one of the existing DB2 tables. If I do so, do I need to recompile all the stored procedures accessing that table? What happens if I don't do that?

Comment: Do you mean procedures written in SQL PL or any external language ? And which DB2 are you talking about (please add the relevant tag) ?

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/10.5?topic=s-alter-table) is pretty clear on that:

> Adding a column to a table will result in invalidation of all packages with `INSERT` usage on the altered table. If the added column is the first user-defined structured type column in the table, packages with `DELETE` usage on the altered table will also be invalidated.

If the new column has a constraint on it, packages with other uses of the table may be invalidated as well.

Invalid packages will be automatically revalidated on their next use. In other words, you don't need to do anything.